# R color vertices by column

Tags: r, colors, igraph, vertices

I am using iGraph to plot graphs. I have just two columns in my matrix- A and B. I need to color my nodes with just 2 colors – that indicates nodes that belong to A and those that belong to B. eg:

```
# k is a df with 2 columns – A and B
k_mx <- as.matrix(k)
k_mx_g <- graph.edgelist(k_mx, directed = FALSE)
V(k_mx_g)$color = ?? ( want blue for A and red for B)
```

Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks,
PD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this dataframe:

```
k <-     structure(list(A = 1:4, B = 5:8), 
                 .Names = c("A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, -4L),
                  class = "data.frame")
```

...  you could use `rep` with an `each` argument. Otherwise they will be sequentially labelled with  c("blue," "red",  "blue", "red",  "blue", "red",  "blue", "red") due to argument recycling:

```
V(k_mx_g)$color <- rep(c("blue", "red"), each=4)
```

Gabor's comment leads me to offer this option, which seems more general:

```
V(k_mx_g)[k$A]$color <- "blue"
V(k_mx_g)[k$B]$color <- "red"
```

Comment: Unfortunately if this works, then it only works by chance, because you have 1:4 in the first column and 5:8 in the second.

Comment: This did start out as a data.frame on its way to a matrix. We were led to believe the all of the first column was "A" and needed to be assigned to "blue" and all of the second column was to be assigned "red". How much chance is involved in that procedure?

Comment: Hmmm, the "another option" is correct I think, but you must be careful to have numbers in the data frame, otherwise you would index with a factor. Also, obviously, this only works if the graph is bipartite, i.e. vertices in column A do not show up in column B, but I guess the poster has such a graph, otherwise the question does not make sense.

Comment: DWin: a comment is not a very convenient way to answer this properly, but how can you be sure that vertices 1:4 are in his first column? Maybe I am missing something here, unfortunately the poster did not provide any data to be sure.

Comment: I must be missing something, since I thought using the dataframe column values would cure any ambiguity.

Comment: When you say `V(k_mx_g)[1:4]`, that means the first four vertices. But you cannot be sure that these are in the first column. They are in your example, but usually this is obviously not the case. As you say yourself, this only works for the simple example you had. That's all I meant.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. To clear all assumptions, I shall explain a bit more. The first column is "Event ID" (E000123, E000345,..) and the second column is "ServerName" (SP645BKP23, SP77PD98,..). They are distinct values and never overlaps. Yes, it can be seen as a bipartite graph. For now, in my data set, I have only one server. So, the graph turns out to be a star-graph. I just need to color my servername differently.